# Thymeleaf Th:Each infinite loop, with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

So I have an object called "StudySet.Java" and it contains a list of objects called "Rows.Java".  I'm trying to represent the list of rows from thymeleaf using a th:each loop, and each row has a string named "question", and a string named "answer".  However whenever I try to represent the list by getting the rows from that studySet, and adding it to the model, there is an infinite loop of question and answers.

I'll put up some code of my controller, and my html page, and if anyone can see where I'm going wrong that would be great.  Thanks in advance and if anyone would like to see more code just let me know.

Controller

```
@Controller
public class StudySetController {

    private StudySetRepository studySetRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "studySet/{studySetId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addPostGet(@PathVariable Long studySetId, ModelMap model) {
        StudySet studySet = studySetRepo.findOne(studySetId);
        model.put("studySet", studySet);
        List<Row> rows = studySet.getRows();
        model.put("rows", rows);

        return "studySet";
    }

    @Autowired
    public void studySetRepo(StudySetRepository studySetRepo) {
        this.studySetRepo = studySetRepo;
    }
}
```

Html Table/ Th:Each Loop

```
<div class="row row-centered">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-centered" style="padding-top:50px;">
        <div class="panel panel-default user-form">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4><span th:text="${studySet.title}"></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr th:each="row : *{rows}" th:object="${row}">
                        <td>
                            <p><span th:text="${row.answer}"></span></p>
                            <p><span th:text="${row.question}"></span></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(rows)}">
    <div style="float: left;">
        There are no rows to display.<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's also a picture of my actual page,  you can't see everything but the list goes on for a long time, and I have two rows assigned to this studySet that are just repeating with dummy information.

[image]

**UPDATE**

It appears that my issue is happening on the Java side, because when I debug, the two rows that are assigned to the study set are just repeating.  However I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that in my domain object `Rows` was returning to `StudySet` as a `List`, and I'm not sure why but that was causing the loop, as soon as I switched it to `HashSet` my problem was solved.

Comment: SET doesn't contain duplicates while List has. So you probably had a lot of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
<tr th:each="row : *{rows}" th:object="${row}">
```

to:

```
<tr th:each="r : ${rows}">
   <td>
   <p><span th:text="${r.answer}"></span></p>
   <p><span th:text="${r.question}"></span></p>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Also, are you sure, that `StudySet` has correct number of `Rows`?

Comment: I changed it and it still is doing the same thing.  Also what  do you mean by does `StudySet` have the right amount of rows?  I'm sort of confused.  It shouldn't matter how many `rows`, because it should loop through each `row`, right?

Comment: I'm using Toad for MySQL, and I only see two `rows` that are assigned to that particular `StudySet`, so I think I should be alright on that.  Also I'm confused because I have plenty other th:each loops in my app, and this is the only that's giving me trouble.

Comment: please also debug on Java side. You can have good data in SQL, but somehow multiplicate it in code. This code should work.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll check it out when I get back to my computer

Comment: So I just got a chance to look, and it is happening on the Java side.  Do you have any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Comment: Never mind I just fixed it, in the domain object I had rows assigned as a `List`, and when I switched it to `HashSet` it worked.